# Delete file if record is not stored in database

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am uploading an article to my website. I first upload the file and then create an entry for the article in the database. So if a file entry is successfully made in the database then everything works fine. But if a file is uploaded and record in the database is not created then I want to delete the file. The problem is if a database error occurs I don't get back to the condition where I wanted to delete the file.
So what am I doing wrong? Following is my code.

**Model**

```
public function create($file_name) {
    $new_article=new Article_model();
    $new_article->active=1;
    $new_article->name=  $file_name;
    $needles=array(' ','_','%','$','#','/','\\');
    foreach($needles as $needle)
    {
        $file_name=str_replace($needle, '-', $file_name);
    }
    $new_article->slug= $file_name;
    $new_article->author_id=$user;
    $new_article->approved=0;
    $new_article->views=0;
    $new_article->downloads=0;
    if($this->db->insert(static::$table_name,$new_article))
    {
        $new_article->id=$this->db->insert_id();
        return $new_article->id;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public function upload_article() 
{
        $config['upload_path']= ARTICLES_PATH;
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'docx|doc|pdf|txt|odt';
        $config['max_size']             = 10000;
        //the following line is in accordance with the auto_load
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('article'))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $error['upload_path']=$config['upload_path'];
            $this->pmp->header('article/new_article', $error);
        }
        else
        {


            $upload_data=$this->upload->data();

            $result=$this->article->create($upload_data['file_name']);
            if($result!==FALSE)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Article Submitted Successfully.');
                redirect('/article/view/'.$result);
            }
            else
            {
                //delete file

                if( ! unlink(ARTICLES_PATH.$upload_data['file_name']))
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Article Submission Failed.');
                }
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Article Submission Failed.');
                redirect('/article/upload_article');
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Is db debug on in db config? Typically this will cause a hault in the script to show you the db error. If it's off then force an error and report what happens: do you get an error message of any kind either in the browser or logs (enable error logging). I don't see anything wrong with any of your conditional statements.

Comment: @Alex Yes debugging is on and yes i get unique constraint failed  error (for slug )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If database debugging is on in the database configuration than script execution will halt via a `show_error()` to show the database error and thus stop your `else` statement from executing. I suggest turning it off (especially in prod environments).

You could also try putting the error suppression symbol in-front of the insert statement (`@`) - but this method I haven't tested as I don't think the db driver uses php triggers for errors.